# SQL Server: is there a performance overhead between '=' and 'like' operators?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

Is there a difference in performance between these two queries?

```
--= operator
SELECT COL1, COL2 
FROM DBO.MYTABLE 
WHERE COL1 = '1'

--like operator
SELECT COL1, COL2 
FROM DBO.MYTABLE 
WHERE COL1 LIKE '1'
```

Basically using LIKE in this case is wrong but database engine accepts this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Checkout the [following post](http://nyc-dba.blogspot.com/2009/04/performance-of-like-vs-in-sql-queries.html).

Quote (in case it goes off-line):

> My knee-jerk response was that the = would be faster, but I thought
>   about it and realized that the query optimizer would actually see them
>   as the same thing. A check of the query plans against a
>   quickly-created tbFoo confirmed it. So that's what I told him.
>
> Except that I realized a moment later that there was a major caveat -
>   the query optimization depends on how the statement is parameterized.
>   If it's purely ad hoc SQL and being compiled at run-time, then the
>   statements are equivalent, but if there's going to be any plan re-use,
>   either by including the statement in a stored proc or preparing it and
>   executing via sp_executesql, the LIKE will impose a significant
>   penalty.
>
> This is because the optimizer doesn't know at compile time whether the
>   parameter to the LIKE operator will contain a wild card, so it can't
>   use the more specific optimization (including index selection) that it
>   could with an = operator. So if you mostly pass parameters without
>   wildcards, you will be executing a suboptimal query plan. Keep this in
>   mind when designing your query!

Comment: +1 but please copy the conclusions of that post into your answer, so that the answer is still relevant even if the blog is at some point unavailable.

Answer (score 3):

It's easy enough to test. I used a table with 6000000 rows doing a comparison with `=` and `like` against a `nvarchar` field that is *not* indexed.

Using `like 'xx'`

```
SQL Server Execution Times:
   CPU time = 6416 ms,  elapsed time = 493 ms.
```

Using `= 'xx'`

```
 SQL Server Execution Times:
   CPU time = 3444 ms,  elapsed time = 212 ms.
```

If you use like with wild card I at least assumed it would be slower still but it was not

Using `like 'xx%'`

```
 SQL Server Execution Times:
   CPU time = 3168 ms,  elapsed time = 296 ms.
```

Using a wild card in the front is a different matter.

Using `like '%xx'`

```
 SQL Server Execution Times:
   CPU time = 18017 ms,  elapsed time = 1530 ms.
```

All these tests are done **without** index on the column so what I actually compare here is the internal operation that do equal compare with a like compare. In the execution plan they are `<Intrinsic FunctionName="like">` for `like` and `<Compare CompareOp="EQ">` for `=`.

The query plans "look" the same for using `like` without `%` and and `=` but they are not. `like` still uses `<Intrinsic FunctionName="like">` even without `%`.

Comment: I'm not sure I agree it's "easy enough to test". I'd prefer a reference to spec here; there seems to be too many variables to reliably correct for. Are you clearing statistics between each query? If not, might the very fact that you've just run almost the same query explain why it's faster the second time around? Note how `xx%` is cheaper in CPU time, but still slower in overall execution than `= xx`. Could it be that the SQL server - or just that machine - is doing *something else entirely* affecting the performance?

Comment: @DavidHedlund - The machine is my local workstation. I did not clear anything between runs so the entire table is in memory. I ran the tests consecutively more than once and I shifted the order between the different statements. There are minor differences between runs but the figures here shows the relation between the different ways.

Comment: @DavidHedlund I would not draw the conclusion that `like 'xx%'` is faster than `= 'xx'` but it **is** faster than `like 'xx'` for some reason.